# Diferença entre insert all e insert com select dual no Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Olá, bom dia!

Estou com algumas dúvidas sobre a melhor forma de inclusão de dados em massa em uma base de dados da Oracle de forma que o banco não sofra tanto. Fazendo algumas pesquisas identifiquei dois métodos para fazer essa inserção e queria entender qual é o método mais performático para efetuar a inclusão de lotes de dados no banco de dados da Oracle e entender a diferença entre os dois métodos e se tem mais algum:

O primeiro caso que vi foi por meio do select dual:

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
      select 8000,0,'Multi 8000',1 from dual
union all select 8001,0,'Multi 8001',1 from dual
```

Não encontrei muita coisa sobre o funcionamento dele e queria entender melhor.
O segundo é o insert all:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (1000, 'IBM')
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (2000, 'Microsoft')
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (3000, 'Google')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Que pelo que entendi ele é como se estivesse fazendo um insert por vez mesmo.

Qual deles é mais performático?

Comment: Execute sua query e veja o tempo de cada uma, a que levar menos tempo para processar será mais performática.

Comment: Você fala de coisas diferentes , inserir dados de base de teste é coisa que se faz de forma esporádica sendo então a performance secundária , melhor focar na qualidade do dado, eu faria um bloco plsql gerando os dados de forma sequencial ou aleátoria. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860428/insert-random-data-in-oracle-table

Comment: Nessa situação que estou fazendo vou inserir dados em uma base de produção no momento de inserção de outro processo que roda em paralelo com o meu (O outro processo inclui mais de 10Gb de dados), seria mais ou menos mil a 2 mil linhas por minuto, fora as atualizações em uma outra tabela. Conversei com o DBA do time eles fazem essas operações usando INSERT ALL só que a base de dados já sofre muito hoje. Queria entender se você sabiam a diferença de performance entre as operações ou se não faz diferença para o banco Oracle?

Comment: Segui o concelho do Ivan Ferrer e testei com mil linhas cada operação, INSERT com dual, INSERT ALL com uma trigger de sequencia (Não estava conseguindo rodar INSERT ALL com o GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY na Primary Key) e um insert um a um. a diferença foi extremamente grande: 1.000 rows affected in 618 ms -> Com Dual, 1.000 rows affected in 1 s 137 ms -> Um a um no begin, 1.000 rows affected in 3 s 166 ms -> Insert all.

Comment: Isso depende muito de como seu Oracle está configurado, onde está rodando, qual versão. É tanta coisa envolvida... Não é só plano de execução não. Vou te dar um exemplo: Se você rodar esse mesmo comando em duas máquinas distintas (com base de dados idênticas), uma com Windows e outra com RedHat terá resultados TOTALMENTE diferentes e distintos.Se for em nuvem também. Então coloca mais detalhes do seu ambiente (pelo menos versão do Oracle e Sistema operacional).